# Getting error in Select from MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql

Getting error in Select from MYSQL on the line `ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(fetch_title);`

> Error msg : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ':09:53' at line 1

```
String test = "27-May-2016 11:09:53";
String fetch_title = "SELECT title FROM competitor_analysis WHERE cron_date_time="+test+"";
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(fetch_title);
```

Comment: on side note, you should start using parameterized query else you gonna invite SQL injection.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap up your date in speech marks in the query.

```
String fetch_title = "SELECT title FROM competitor_analysis WHERE cron_date_time='"+test+"'";
```

Comment: Ok, you were faster ;)

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the string in your MySQL query as a string; you aren't doing this which results in the error.

So you need to insert in `''` in your case.

So you could do it like this:

```
String fetch_title = "SELECT title FROM competitor_analysis WHERE cron_date_time='"+test+"'";
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is unsafe because it is conducive to [SQL Injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you need to use a `PreparedStatement` instead as next:

```
String test = "27-May-2016 11:09:53";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT title FROM competitor_analysis WHERE cron_date_time=?"
);
ps.setString(1, test);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

This approach has 2 main advantages:

1. It is safer as mentioned above
2. It is less error prone, as you don't have to escape the value explicitly anymore since it will be managed by the driver itself