# Using single quotes in a search bar

Tags: java, mysql, sql, search, quotes

I'm trying to search for entries in my SQL database, but whenever I input a single quote in the search bar and run it, I get an error. When I type a specific name, it returns the right entries from the database. I've read about using '', and escaping, and using prepared statements but either none of the answers are the right fit for my case or I'm not understanding something conceptually. (I'm a beginner) Thanks in advance! :)

Below is the code for my jsp file, what it looks like when I run, and what happens when I insert a single quotation.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>List of Entries</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Retrieve Data</h1>
    <form method="post" action="index.jsp">
        Search <input type="text" name="search"
            placeholder="Enter your search here..." /> 
            <input type="submit"
            value="Search" name="submit"/>
    </form><br><br>
    <%
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ResultSet rs2 = null;


        try {
            String searchReq = request.getParameter("search");
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //make connection to db
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/profile", "root", "");

            //create a statement
            stmt = con.createStatement();

            //executes SQL query
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM person WHERE Name LIKE '%"+ searchReq +"%'");
    %>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Name</b></td>
            <td><b>Birthday</b></td>
            <td><b>Address</b></td>
            <td><b>Gender</b></td>
            <td><b>School</b></td>
        </tr>

        <%
            try {
                    while (rs.next()) {
        %>

        <tr>
            <td><%=rs.getString("Name")%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString("Birthday")%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString("Address")%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString("Gender")%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString("School")%></td>
        </tr>

        <%
            }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        %>

    </table>
    <%
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();

        }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

[jsp page with search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7RrF.png)

[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Cu3.png)

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37479030/1997376

Comment: Don't string tighter your query, use parameters. Also what SQL are you using? (SQL-Server, MYSQL, Oracle)

Comment: @Chuck MYSQL. Sorry what do you mean by string tighter?

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` instead. And get rid of all that Java code and SQL statements from your JSP page. That logic should be in a servlet or a custom tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your main problem is here:

```
"SELECT * FROM person WHERE Name LIKE '%"+ searchReq +"%'"
```

when variable `searchReq` contains single quote, you're creating sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE Name LIKE '%'%'
                                       ^ sql engine consider this as end of string literal
```

when database tries to parse this query, it finds correct part `SELECT * FROM person WHERE Name LIKE '%'` and then invalid one `%'`

this is the same as in pure java, if you want to declare string with `"` inside, if you try:

```
String s = "my string with " quote";
                           ^ java considers this as end of string literal
```

you will get syntax error message, you need to escape such symbol, for java it is `\"`

so, to fix this, you need either use parametric queries, or check [sql standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt):

> <character representation> ::= <nonquote character> | <quote symbol>
>
> <quote symbol> ::= <quote><quote>

so, single quote should be present/escaped as double single quote `''`

so, if you just replace all `'` with `''` - you will get rid of sql injections and fix failing query.

the simplest way is `searchReq = searchReq.replaceAll("'", "''");`

but, sql operator `LIKE` has 2 additional special symbols `%` and `_`

> If an <escape character> is not specified, then each <underscore> character in P represents an arbitrary character specifier, each <percent> character in P represents an arbitrary string specifier, and each character in P that is neither the <underscore> character nor the <percent> character represents itself.

consider what will be found by your query if user inputs these symbols?

hint: take a look at standard:

> <like predicate> ::= <match value> [ NOT ] LIKE <pattern> [ ESCAPE <escape character> ]

Comment: Wow, thank you for the thorough answer! :) However I'm still not totally sure what to do with the information

Comment: @episkeyyy try to forget about java for moment, just try to create different sql queries, create test row, which percent sign in it and then try to construct like-query which will return only this row, not all rows